# How to create a single shared framework between iOS and OS X

Tags: macos, core-data, frameworks, ios8

I am attempting to create a framework to hold the common entity classes for an app that runs on iOS and OS X. Currently I am just including the files in each target but that requires changing the data model so it get the class from the current target (since in Swift you have to specify the module that has the class in the model file). This of course means I forget at times and things don't work.

The obvious solution is to create a shared framework that holds the entity classes so that the data model always points to the same place.

The problem is there doesn't seem to be any way to create a framework that builds on both platforms.

Has anyone found a way to create a single framework, or library, that works on both platforms?

Comment: There was a very good WWDC session on exactly this topic this year, [Sharing Code Between iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#233)

Comment: This article explains quite well what must be done: http://appracatappra.com/2018/03/building-cross-platform-universal-frameworks-using-swift/

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you wish to create a single dynamic framework binary, here are the steps you can follow (as outlined in http://colemancda.github.io/2015/02/11/universal-ios-osx-framework):

#### 1. Change the project's valid architectures and supported platforms.

This should change your framework's and test unit's valid architectures and supported platforms as well. If not, then manually change them to inherit from the project's build settings.

[image: Step One]

- Base SDK: I recommend OS X, but it will work with iOS too. Note that with with iOS as the base SDK, "My Mac" target is separated into 3 different targets.
- Supported Platforms: `macosx iphoneos iphonesimulator`
- Valid Architectures: `arm64 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64`

#### 2. Change the search paths for the Unit Test bundle

[image: Step Two]

- Runpath Search Paths: `$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks @executable_path/../Frameworks @loader_path/../Frameworks`
- Framework Search Paths: `$(SDKROOT) $(inherited)`

Its a better solution than having two separate targets.

Comment: When doing it this way, how can you change the deployment target for iOS to enforce a minimum version? You can set it for OS X (e.g., 10.10), but there is no setting for iOS unlike when you have two targets.

Comment: @BytesGuy Add a user defined setting IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET and set it to 8.0 (minimum supported)

Comment: @jeef No it doesn't  :(

Comment: I believe as of version 0.9.0 it will work with carthage (not out on home-brew yet)

Comment: How is the fact that from Xcode 7 you are no longer allowed to link together files built for different platforms affect this solution? see [here](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQwpPqrdhi1Wseauib2tNzFLAZM4H3uWBJRTL4e3mDTBy)

Comment: I don't have the `Supported Platforms` and `Valid Architectures` options in my settings in Xcode 7.3 :(

Comment: Good solution. But the problem I seem to be having with it is that, the moment I change the base SDK to Mac and try to build my DemoApp iOS target, I get a lot of errors regarding iOS-specific headers e.g. `#import <UIKit/UIKit>`. I could wrap al those in `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE..`, but given the size of my code base, that would be way more trouble than just having two targets and split platform-specific source files by target membership.

Comment: It does work with Carthage, and in fact this is how WebKit is compiled. If you want Carthage to compile for the multiple platforms, you just need to add extra Schemas specific to each platform, but still single target.

Comment: @ColemanCDA...Please add script here to create a single framework which will supports both iOS and MacOS

Comment: I have to add a couple of things here, probably related to the last xcode version. (a) The project itself should be cross-platform; (b) In case that yoru framework on different platforms needs to link to different 3rd party frameworks (opencv2 in my case) then you kind of having trouble and much more complicated hacks required. Ping me if you need details.

Comment: **Important caveat**: If you set your framework's base SDK to macOS, you will encounter "No such module" errors in the build logs while exporting string localizations for your iOS app. What worked for me was switching it back to iOS since I'm really using the framework for an iOS app⸺the only reason why it also supports macOS is so that I can use some of my iOS app's Swift data models in a command line tool project to generate JSON objects.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out the answer is super simple but not very obvious, at least not until after I posted this question and worked on something else.

All that needs to be done is to make a framework target for each platform but then set the product names to be the same. As this is also the module name in Swift you can then set the class field in the Core Data model to one value and have it work on both platforms.

The setup I'm using is to include the model files in both frameworks but to include the model itself directly into each app target.

You should also be able to set both apps to have the same product name and have everything work but I didn't test it and the frameworks allow you to have `MyApp` and `MyAppMobile` if you want.

Comment: This is kind of not really an answer because you are making two frameworks not just 1

Comment: This answer is wrong. The generated framework will only support one SDK. Once generated, it will overwrite an existing framework with the same name.

Comment: Wrong is a strong word. It is certainly less than optimal, hence the reason that it is not the accepted answer. It does however meet the need of allowing a Core Data model and associated class files to be shared in both an iOS and OS X project. That was the original issue and this route did succeed in working around the issue.

Comment: @theMikeSwan I did like that a couple of times and it just works. Nothing gets rewritten because the different frameworks are stored in different folders. But I am not satisfied. Have you found a way to have the frameworks named, I don't know, "Project-iOS.framework" and "Project-macOS.framework" but then you import them as "import Project"?