# How to set up a shared framework for iOS and OS X

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, frameworks

I want to build a shared framework for iOS8 and OS X just as described in this [workshop of Apple from the WWDC14](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#233)

I've followed all their steps, but in my project (which is in Swift and not Obj-C), the framework could not be found, even after adding

> $(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)

to the Header Search Paths of the app. I'll explain in detail how I came to this point:

1. I create a new project with a simple **Single View Application**.
2. In the App, I create a new target, which is a **Cocoa Application**.
3. Inside the Example App, I create a new **Cocoa Touch Framework**.
4. In the new framework, I add a new target, which is a **Cocoa Framework**. This is the initial project setup.

[image: Xcode Project after Step 4]

5. I add a *Common* Group in which I will save the code, which should be shared.
6. I select the **Build Settings** of the **Mac** Framework and replace the text of **Public Headers Folder Path** with

`ExampleFramework`

7. I repeat step 6 for the **iOS** Framework
8. Just as in the video, I get a build error after I add this to  **AppDelegate** of my Mac App:

`import ExampleFramework`

9. I select the **Build Settings** of my Mac app and add to the **Header Search Paths**

`$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)`

10. I try to build the Mac app, but still get the error that

> there is no such module ExampleFramework

11. Lastly, I try to fix the error by adding the ExampleFramework **Mac** target to the **Target Dependencies** and **Link Binary With Libraries** of the **Mac** app, but still get the same error.

Even after building the Framework, Xcode still doesn't find the module "ExampleFramework" in my AppDelegate. If I replace the

`import ExampleFramework`

with the name of the target framework, which is *ExampleAppMacFramework*, I get the error:

> Could not build Objective-C module "ExampleAppMacFramework"

Do you have an idea what I do wrong, and maybe how I could do it else? I've tried [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811170/how-to-create-a-single-shared-framework-between-ios-and-os-x), but it didn't work for me either.